# What is the equivalent of a C# gridview in java GUI?

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, swing, gridview

I am trying to learn java, I am working on a simple program where I fetch a list of records from a collection(table) and display the information.

I want to display only few descriptive columns but when the user selects a record(row) he would get the entire info on that particular record in some other jframe  or dialog box(not sure how I gonna go from here).

I did work on C# and asp a bit ,I am looking for something similar to a gridview  in c# ,

PS:It would also help if you guys give me some sort of pointer how exactly I would do this..

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to use a `JTable` to display data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fetch a list of records from a collection(table) and display the information.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for the basics of displaying data in a tabular format.

> I want to display only few descriptive columns but when the user selects a record(row) he would get the entire info

You will need to create a custom TableModel to do this. See the `JButtonTableModel.java` example from [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for an example of how you can control the columns of data you want to see. The RowTableModel does most of the work for you, you just need to implement a couple of methods.